# Windows Phone 8 app authenticate with Facebook

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is possible to Windows Phone 8 app use Facebook authentication service to log in into my app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Facebook Graph API in your app to execute your requirement.

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_Facebook_Graph_API_in_Windows_Phone